# Count from 0 to 100 in 7 seconds while doing an jQuery.animate() for a progress bar

Tags: jquery

I've a simple progress bar that has to go from 0 to 100% width in 7 seconds. I've no problem handling operations, it just need to be 7 seconds long.

The code is actually so simple:

```
$('.progress-bar').animate({width:'100%'}, 7000);
```

The width of the progress is 0% so just I need to animate it to 100%. My problem is that I also need to count from 0 to 100 to show the percentage in the same way I do for the progress (within 7 seconds).

How I can do it?

Thank you!

Comment: to clarify, do you need to show how many percentage is the bar within that 7s?

Comment: @NiftyDude: yes, that's it. Thank you. Getting, for example, the element width is also right to know.

Comment: Do you know in HTML5 you have a nice and customizable `<progress>` tag? [More info](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/C23YM/9/

Basically pass in a function to `step` option, and on each `step` call, check whether `width` is the one being animated since you might have, for example two properties being animated.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> Note that the step function is called for each animated property on
>   each animated element. For example, given two list items, the step
>   function fires four times at each step of the animation

```
$('.progress-bar').animate(
    {width:'100%'}, 
    {
        duration:7000,
        step: function(now, fx) {
           if(fx.prop == 'width') {
               $(this).html(Math.round(now * 100) / 100 + '%');
           }
        }
    }        
);​
```

Comment: $(this).html(Math.round(now * 100 / 100) + '%'); this will fix the round to whole number.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
var starttime = (new Date()).getTime();

function updateTime() {
    var timediffPerc = ((new Date()).getTime() - starttime) / 70000;
    $('#percentage').text(timediffPerc.toFixed(2) + "%");
    if(timediffPerc<100) window.setTimeout(updateTime, 100);
}
```

You'll need a HTML element with id="percentage" where the percentage will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use animate "from" "to" logic;

```
var _start = {property: 0};
var _end = {property: 100};

jQuery(_start).animate(_end, {
    duration: 7000,
    step: function() {
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', this.property + "%");        
    //console.log( 'Current percentage is ' + this.property );// You can write this to your bar

    }
});
```

You can refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

you can search like "step" in that page

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't see how from/to logic and Google it doesn't help. This doesn't works out-of-the-box, it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: from is not defined` and I don't see where to get documentation for that. Can you reference me to something? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the animate documentation http://api.jquery.com/animate/ there is a step method which you can use and that is called at every step of an animation.

> The second version of .animate() provides a step option — a callback
>   function that is fired at each step of the animation. This function is
>   useful for enabling custom animation types or altering the animation
>   as it is occurring. It accepts two arguments (now and fx), and this is
>   set to the DOM element being animated.
>
> now: the numeric value of the property being animated at each step fx:
>   a reference to the jQuery.fx prototype object, which contains a number
>   of properties such as elem for the animated element, start and end for
>   the first and last value of the animated property, respectively, and
>   prop for the property being animated.

So you can use that to get the current width value as in percent you should get a value that matches exactly the width of the element (example get 70 for 70%)