# jquery animate progress bar percentage faster than the bar (step)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, progress

i'm trying to code a (fake) animate progress bar in jquery, i'm using the function animate(), this is my code:

```
$("#progress_bar").animate({width:"100%"},{
                    step: function( now, fx ) {
                    var data =  Math.round(now);
                    $( "#percent" ).html(data+' % ')},duration:8000}//function pourcentages


                ); //animate
```

The problem is about the percent, it's much fater than the bar (which is a div go from 0 to 100% width), the counter is finish before than the bar reach the 100%. Do someone can help me to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced your code and it works fine.

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xV7uN/)

Are you animating only one property ? If not, you might want to use something like this :

```
$("#progress_bar").animate({width:"100%"},{
    step: function( now, fx ) {
        if(fx.prop == 'width') { //If you animate more than 1 property
            var data =  Math.round(now);
            $( "#percent" ).html(data+' % ');
        }
    },duration:8000}//function pourcentages 
); //animate
```

Check a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313019/count-from-0-to-100-in-7-seconds-while-doing-an-jquery-animate-for-a-progress) for more info

Answer (score 0):

It probably animates in pixels even if you declare your instruction in %.

The output you receive is most likely the widht in pixels of the element at a given point.

Try something like this :

```
$("#progress_bar").animate({width:"100%"},{
    step: function( now, fx ) {
    var max_width = [...];
    var actual_width =  Math.round(now);
    var data_perc = (actual_width / max_width) * 100;

    $( "#percent" ).html(data_perc+' % ')},duration:8000}//function pourcentages


); //animate
```

Replace [..] with the max width of your bar (probably the width of your bar wrapper).

Ex :

```
var max_width = $('#bar_wrapper').width();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even if i false the user by showing %, still, my width go from 0 to 100, it should follow the bar....

Comment: Ok, i found the problem, i use css3 gradient as backgoround for my bar, it makes the animation slowler, without gradient it work perfectly.